# Android parse.com setObjectId

Tags: android, parse-platform

How set objectId with Parse.com with primary key.Can you help me ?
When i create new row, i want setObjectId of row.

```
  final ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject(ChapsModel.PARSE_OBJECT);
            parseObject.put(ChapsModel.PARSE_FIELD_NAME_CHAPS,
                            chapsModel.get(i)
                                      .getNamChap());
            parseObject.put(ChapsModel.PARSE_FIELD_LINK_CHAP,
                            chapsModel.get(i)
                                      .getLinkChap());
            parseObject.put(ChapsModel.PARSE_FILED_TEAM_TRANSLATE,
                            chapsModel.get(i)
                                      .getTeamTranslate());
            parseObject.put(ChapsModel.PARSE_FIELD_OBJECT_MANGA,
                            ParseObject.createWithoutData(MangaModel.PARSE_OBJECT,
                                                          chapsModel.get(i)
                                                                    .getObjectManga()));
            parseObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(final ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Log.e(">>>>>",
                              "done" + ojectId);
                  //      parseObject.setObjectId(ojectId);

                    } else {
                        Log.e(">>>>>",
                              "else" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: objectIds cannot be changed in offline mode.
```

Log: 
Sorry my english. thank

Comment: Not sure how to do it, but why do you want to change the object id?

Comment: because i have save id with hashcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to set objectId with Parse.com with primary key.

Although parse.com doesn't allow us to set the objectId of a row, you can create a new column named anything you want and you can set that new column to any objectId you want.  For example, you can create a new column named myObjectId and set it to a string.

From the parse.com website at https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud_code
The Data Browser

The Data Browser is the web UI where you can update and create objects in each of your apps. Here, you can see the raw JSON values that are saved that represents each object in your class.

When using the interface, keep in mind the following:

The objectId, createdAt, updatedAt fields cannot be edited (these are set automatically).